# How do I store and retrieve TimeUUIDType types with Net::Cassandra::Easy?

Tags: perl, cassandra, uuid

Doing the following:

```
my $c = Net::Cassandra::Easy->new(server => 'localhost', port => '9160', keyspace => 'Keyspace1'); $c->connect();

my $uuid_bin = Data::UUID->new()->create_bin();
eval { $result = $c->mutate([$key],
                            family => 'StandardByUUID1',
                            insertions => { $uuid_bin => '123' });
};
warn $@ if $@;
```

Result is a:

```
Net::GenCassandra::InvalidRequestException
```

I didn't see anything similar to Net::Cassandra::Easy::pack_decimal for UUIDs.

Comment: Got a quick response from Ted Zlatanov the author of the Net::Cassandra::Easy module, sounds like the module doesn't yet support TimeUUIDTypes (as of v0.10)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the Java code here will be useful: http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/FAQ#working_with_timeuuid_in_java